# Change Character Spacing

Tags: javascript, html, css, char

I was trying to find out how to convert normal chars (ABC) to full-width characters (ＡＢＣ). I can't find how so I'm reaching to you guys. I don't have any Javascript code yet. Here is my HTML:

```
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Space+Mono" rel="stylesheet">

<h1>Text convertor 2000</h1>

<textarea placeholder="Text Input" id="textarea_left" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
    <textarea placeholder="Text Output" id="textarea_right" spellcheck="false"></textarea>


</body>



</html>
```

and css (even if it might be not useful):

```
    body { 
 background: linear-gradient(270deg, #ffa6ff, #6bffff);
  background-size: 200% 200%;
  -webkit-animation: backgroundGradient 15s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: backgroundGradient 15s linear infinite;
  animation: backgroundGradient 15s linear infinite;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed');

h1 {
    font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-left: 640px;
    color: #631b87;
    -webkit-animation: simpleColorChange 5s ease infinite;
    -moz-animation: simpleColorChange 5s ease infinite;
    -o-animation: simpleColorChange 5s ease infinite;
    animation: simpleColorChange 5s ease infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes simpleColorChange {
  0% {
    color: #6c4df0
  }
  50% {
    color: #b146d4
  }
  100% {
    color: #6c4df0
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes simpleColorChange {
  0% {
    color: #6c4df0
  }
  50% {
    color: #b146d4
  }
  100% {
    color: #6c4df0
  }
}

@-o-keyframes simpleColorChange {
  0% {
    color: #6c4df0
  }
  50% {
    color: #b146d4
  }
  100% {
    color: #6c4df0
  }
}

@keyframes simpleColorChange {
   0% {
    color: #6c4df0
  }
  50% {
    color: #b146d4
  }
  100% {
    color: #6c4df0
  }
}

#textarea_left {
    margin-left: 280px;
    margin-top: 80px;
    width: 650px;
    height: 550px;
    resize: none;
    border: none;
    overflow: auto;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
}

#textarea_right {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 80px;
    width: 650px;
    height: 550px;
    resize: none;
    border: none;
    overflow: auto;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: #585652;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: #585652;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  color: #585652;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  color: #585652;
}

@-webkit-keyframes backgroundGradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }

  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }

  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes backgroundGradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }

  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }

  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
}

@keyframes backgroundGradient {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }

  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }

  100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the **[`letter-spacing` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/letter-spacing)** of the output `textarea` to a relative value (like `em`) and copy the value from the input `textarea` to the outupt `textarea` on the `input` event:

```js
// Get DOM references:
var input = document.getElementById("textarea_left");
var output = document.getElementById("textarea_right");

// Set up an event listener on the input textarea for when it receives input
input.addEventListener("input", function(){
  // Set the text of the output textarea to the input textarea's text
  output.value = input.value;
});
```

```css
textarea { width:200px; height:200px; }
.input { font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
/* Setting the letter-spacing to 1em creates a space of the height of
   one letter "M" for each character. Change it in decimals to go bigger
   or smaller as needed       */
.output { font-family:serif; letter-spacing:1em; }
```

```html
<h1>Text convertor 2000</h1>

<textarea placeholder="Text Input" id="textarea_left" spellcheck="false" class="input"></textarea>
<textarea placeholder="Text Output" id="textarea_right" spellcheck="false" class="output"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding but it's not really what I meant, I meant converting to this type of full-width : Ｈｅｙ　ｈｏｗ　ａｒｅ　ｙｏｕ

Comment: What algorithm are you using to get to that width? What "type" of full width is that? See my updated answer.

Comment: I'm actually trying to recreate a converter that I already know, so I actually don't know at all of how it works. It's ranging from U+FF0x to U+FF9x in the unicode consortium code chart. Here is the convertor: https://lingojam.com/VaporwaveTextGenerator

Comment: It's not really about changing the characters. It's just the spacing of the characters. My updated answer does this.

Comment: I know see how it works. Thank you very much for taking time to do this and helping me! :)